# Ruby - how to assign ID for each line in a text file

Tags: ruby, file-io

I want to create a localization file, which consist of ID-ed lines; each line can be called by its ID and shown in the program afterwards.

The method I was using before was using win32api using .ini file, which can read a "pair" of key and value. And this is the most easiest way to do it by calling its key. But I encountered unicode problem, hence, non-standard characters are read in ANSI and shown as random boxes.
The program was compiled in ruby 1.8.1 and there is no way to upgrade its ruby version as I do not have its source code.

> So, my question is, how to call specific line by calling its ID from a
>   file **WITHOUT looping across the entire file** ? the ID must not only
>   contains number and only ruby methods involved. The text file must be in a plain .txt

I tried it before using combination of methods from String, IO and File class and the result is, I have to **loop across the entire file** first to search the specific ID and return its value. The file was huge, and I don't think this is the proper way if I must read a text around 10 times in a second.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how you could do it without reading the entire file. Of course, you only need to read the file once, if you keep it in memory, and subsequently have random to all lines.

Comment: I ask this because of I think this will hinder the performance if I have to read a text many times in short time. Tell me, if a file was read, will it persist in the memory on the next time I read the same file, it read the memory, or, reassign it to memory again ? Correct me If I'm wrong, I don't really understand about memory access (well, ruby don't explicitly access a memory address like C++)

Comment: Or, I could just create a hash that store all the key and value from the file when the program starts ?

Comment: After opening a file, store the content in a variable, and it won't read the file again.

Comment: It's possible to read the entire file into memory (e.g. using `File.read`); you can then work with the returned data, and the file won't be read again unless you do it explicitly. You can also read the file line-by-line and generate an in-memory data-structure as you go, thereby removing the need to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the feedback. I'll be using hash to store the contents and read the text from there. The ID saved as hash key symbol (eg :Someting), not as string for better memory lookup. I'll work on my code now. :)

Comment: When you say 'localization file', do you mean a file with the strings for your application? If so, I would suggest using an XML document since they can be parsed quickly with gems like nokogiri.

Comment: @JustinKo - Yes, that also preferable. But in this case, I want to try not to use additional gems/extension. The localization file should able to be edited by everyone without any scripting skills, and saved into UTF-8 encoding easily. I'm going with text file first, if there is a performance issue, then, I will use XML. Indeed XML would best suited for database such as localization, I would use it if not working in this app. Thanks for the mentioning this.